# Jquery - disable select when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to do my own drag and drop function using jquery library.  But everytime I mousedown on an image, then mousemove, my browser "highlights" or "selects" the image, which disrupts my mousemove operation.

How do I disable the select/highlight?  I tried `$('img').onselectstart = function() {return false;}`, but that didn't work.

Comment: When you say "your own", do you mean without jQueryUI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could prevent the default behaviour of the `dragstart` event...

```
$('img').bind('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2kqZ/).

Comment: Nice. This works for me. It does lock down an element which has draggable="false" attribute, but doesn't prevent the ugly highlighting that comes with mouse selection.

Answer (score 9):

jQuery UI has an undocumented method that it uses to disable browser text selection.  You can call it using this syntax:

```
$('IMG').disableSelection();
```

Remember that you need to be using jQuery UI (which I assume you are).

Comment: This works wonders! If you have jQuery UI then I recommend this solution.

Comment: If it's undocumented, it could be removed at any time. Something to consider.